# Bootstrap carousel 2 items per slide javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

I have an array; that looks like this:

```
array = [
{
    id:1,
    metadata:['object','object']
},
{
    id:2,
    metadata:['object','object']
},
{
    id:3,
    metadata:['object','object']
}]
```

this is what I'm doing:

```
array.forEach(function(elem){
      output_info +=`<div class="col-md-12">
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
             <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>


            <div class="carousel-inner">`


      elem.metadata.forEach(function(trip){
        output_info += each_metadata_html(trip)
      })
      output_info += `</div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>`
  })
  console.log("this is output", output_info)
  $('#results').html(output_info) then I throw this inside my results tab.
```

Which looks like this

```
 <div class="row" id="results"></div>
```

each_devices_html takes in an metadata object.

```
function each_metadata_html(elem){
  return `<div class="item">
          <p>`+elem.name+` </p>
      </div>`
}
```

Problem:
  The code doesn't display carousel; but instead it looks like this:

[the element looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6nn.png)
 [everything is stacked together..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9hnf.png)

What I'm trying to do is; with the given array above:

I want to be able to. In this case I'd like to be able to display 3 different carousel in one page; then caraousel having 2 metadata per slides.

Comment: use key ctrl + m

Comment: What does tha tdo.

Comment: Does carousel work if you try as static HTML without the late bindings.. Could be past rendering point..

Comment: They do display; they're just all stacked together..

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem using the Snippet tool in the editor below or in jsfiddle, codepen (both of these have bootstrap defaults)?

[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)